# Playing audio via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, error-handling

This is my code:

```
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
p.play()
```

but its showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/devsi/PycharmProjects/introtoeng/Music from drive.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\devsi\PycharmProjects\introtoeng\venv\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\devsi\PycharmProjects\introtoeng\venv\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 170, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('.\\' + libname)
  File "C:\Users\devsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I am new to python and dont really know what this means, any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that the `vlc` module that you have imported could not be found.

Install the module first.
It can be done via

```
pip install python-vlc
```

or

```
pip3 install python-vlc
```

depending on the python version you are using *(python2/python3)*

Comment: I already installed it, but still shows this message

Comment: There can be a problem with your editor or environment, restart it again or try using some other editor.

Comment: I think there is some error with vlc, my friend tried it and also got the same error.After doing some research,I found that alot of people have the same problem with vlc,though your effort is appreciated!Thanks so much!